# Endianess of txids when calculating Merkle Root from getblocktemplate

Tags: merkle-tree, mining-software, getblocktemplate, endianness

## I am trying to solve a merkle root from a previously mined block.

Specifically this block...
https://www.blockchain.com/en/btc/block/000000000003ba27aa200b1cecaad478d2b00432346c3f1f3986da1afd33e506

TXHash1: 8c14f0db3df150123e6f3dbbf30f8b955a8249b62ac1d1ff16284aefa3d06d87

TXHash2: fff2525b8931402dd09222c50775608f75787bd2b87e56995a7bdd30f79702c4

TXHash3: 6359f0868171b1d194cbee1af2f16ea598ae8fad666d9b012c8ed2b79a236ec4

TXHash4: e9a66845e05d5abc0ad04ec80f774a7e585c6e8db975962d069a522137b80c1d

https://medium.com/@stolman.b/1-4-hashing-transactions-txids-to-find-the-merkle-root-3aa5255f8de8

The blogpost above goes through the process of converting the transaction IDs to little endian.
To solve the merkle root.

## Question: When mining new blocks using getblocktemplate

According to the bitcoin developer [documentation](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/getblocktemplate.html), transaction hashes are given in little endian already.

```
transactions
"hash" : "xxxx",             (string) hash encoded in little-endian hexadecimal (including witness data)
```

So... do I skip that step ?